# Black screen on launch - iOS app

Tags: ios, freeze, launch

Some of my users are saying that my app creates a black, empty screen on launch, which I simply cannot reproduce. Does anyone have advice on how to go about solving this?

I have some SQLite data that gets loaded into an NSDictionary object right after launch--in a file called SecondaryLoadingViewController.m, on a background thread. This view controller merely displays a replica of our splash screen image, which definitely isn't empty...or black. I'm not blocking the main thread, and this only happens for about two or three seconds on an iPhone 5.

Furthermore, I've got NSAssert statements throughout my database code, so if something were to go wrong in there, you'd think that would result in a crash--not a black, empty screen.

I'm lost here. I guess I could email the affected users and ask them to use an application like iExplorer to send me all of their user data in an attempt to reproduce the problem for once?

Any other ideas would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: do you use any analytics framework? if yes, maybe you can trace back some data from its logs

Comment: it might be because of splash screen . you might be missing some retina or non retina , ios 6 or 7 screens. please recheck that also.

Comment: Do you have a splash image setup in the application bundle?

Comment: @shujatAli, I'm not missing any image assets. I'm only supporting iOS 7.0+, and I've tested on both retina and non-retina devices.

Comment: @LenaBru, Yes, I've got all necessary LaunchImages bundled, and then some.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, I'm using Flurry Analytics, but this doesn't appear to be an exception or crash, so I don't think it's showing up on Flurry.

Comment: the fact that you're supporting only iOS 7 does not mean it doesnt run on iOS6...

Comment: @LenaBru, You're definitely wrong about that. The app requires iOS 7.0 or higher. Anyway, the problem has been fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the black screen only showed up on the iPod, not the iPhone or iPad. The problem was this key in the plist file:

"Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)"

Notice the "(iPhone)" at the end. I have no idea how that got there, but deleting "(iPhone)" from the key solved everything.